# Deliver the first item immediately, 'debounce' following items

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Consider the following use case:

- need to deliver first item as soon as possible
- need to *debounce* following events with 1 second timeout

I ended up implementing custom operator based on `OperatorDebounceWithTime` then using it like this

```
.lift(new CustomOperatorDebounceWithTime<>(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation()))
```

`CustomOperatorDebounceWithTime` delivers the first item immediately then uses `OperatorDebounceWithTime` operator's logic to *debounce* later items.

Is there an easier way to achieve described behavior? Let's skip the `compose` operator, it doesn't solve the problem. I'm looking for a way to achieve this without implementing custom operators.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Update:
From @lopar's comments a better way would be:

```
Observable.from(items).publish(publishedItems -> publishedItems.limit(1).concatWith(publishedItems.skip(1).debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
```

Would something like this work:

```java
String[] items = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.from(items);
Observable.concat(
  myObservable.first(), 
  myObservable.skip(1).debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
).subscribe(s -> 
  System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: You could also prevent making dual subscriptions (which in the cold observable case is doing the work twice, and in the hot case could potentially be out of sync) with `publish`:   
    `Observable.from(items).publish(publishedItems -> publishedItems.limit(1).concatWith(publishedItems.skip(1).debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))`

Also note that `first` will blow up if the `Observable` is empty, so unless that is desired behavior, you'll probably want `limit(1)`.

Comment: @lopar thanks for the tip. I'm a beginner with RxJava and I'm trying to learn by helping others :).

Comment: I was waiting for the solution proposed by @lopar. I think the second one may not work in some situations. `myObservable.skip(1)` may subscribe after the first item has been published so it will skip the second element.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK, your original answer was good, no worries about being a beginner! :) Glad I could help tweak it a bit.

Comment: When using the publish form, you should not .skip(1). Because the observable is using the same subscription it will continue from the same spot. It should just be ```Observable.from(items).publish(publishedItems -> publishedItems.limit(1).concatWith(publishedItems.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))```

Comment: use .take(1) instead of .limit(1) in version 2

Comment: I used this answer time ago. And I just realesed is wrong. The problem is that the debounce hides the problem. Don't write the skip(1) or you will lost the second item every time. [Full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497411/842697)

Answer (score 18):

The answers by @LortRaydenMK and @lopar are best, but I wanted to suggest something else in case it happened to work better for you or for someone in a similar situation.

There's a variant of `debounce()` that takes a function that decides how long to debounce this particular item for. It specifies this by returning an observable that completes after some amount of time. Your function could return `empty()` for the first item and `timer()` for the rest. Something like (untested):

```
String[] items = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};
Observable.from(items)
    .debounce(item -> item.equals("one")
            ? Observable.empty()
            : Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

The trick is that this function would have to know which item is the first. Your sequence might know that. If it doesn't, you might have to `zip()` with `range()` or something. Better in that case to use the solution in the other answer.

Comment: There sholud be TimeUnit.SECONDS (you miss the "S").

However it's the only example of usage of this function which I found.
It really helped me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution using RxJava 2.0, translated from [the answer for the same question for RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957168/rx-debounce-operator-with-first-and-last), which combines throttleFirst and debounce, then removes duplicates.

```java
private <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> debounceImmediate() {
    return observable  -> observable.publish(p -> 
        Observable.merge(p.throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 
            p.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).distinctUntilChanged());
} 

@Test
public void testDebounceImmediate() {
    Observable.just(0, 100, 200, 1500, 1600, 1800, 2000, 10000)
        .flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(v, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(w -> v))
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " T=" + v))
            .compose(debounceImmediate())
            .blockingSubscribe(v -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Debounced: " + v));
}
```

The approach of using limit() or take() doesn't seem to handle long lived data flows, where I might want to continually observe, but still act immediately for the first event seen for a time.

Answer (score 8):

The [LordRaydenMK and lopar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145789/842697) has a problem: you always lose the second item. I supose that no one realeased this before because if you have a debounce you normally has a lot of events and the second is discarted with the debounce anyways. The correct way to never lose an event is:

```
observable
    .publish(published ->
        published
            .limit(1)
            .concatWith(published.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
```

And don't worry, you are not going to get any duplicated event. If you aren't sure about it you can run this code and check it yourself:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .publish(published ->
        published
            .limit(1)
            .concatWith(published))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the version of `debounce` that takes a function and implement the function in this way:

```
    .debounce(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
        private AtomicBoolean isFirstEmission = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(String s) {
             // note: standard debounce causes the first item to be
             // delayed by 1 second unnecessarily, this is a workaround
             if (isFirstEmission.getAndSet(false)) {
                 return Observable.just(s);
             } else {
                 return Observable.just(s).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             }
        }
    })
```

The first item emits immediately. Subsequent items are delayed by a second. If a delayed observable doesn't terminate before the following item arrives, it's cancelled, so the expected debounce behavior is fulfilled.

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin extension functions based on @lopar's comment:

```java
fun <T> Flowable<T>.debounceImmediate(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Flowable<T> {
    return publish {
        it.take(1).concatWith(it.debounce(timeout, unit))
    }
}

fun <T> Observable<T>.debounceImmediate(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Observable<T> {
    return publish {
        it.take(1).concatWith(it.debounce(timeout, unit))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ngrx - rxjs solution, split the pipe to two

```
onMyAction$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(ofType<any>(ActionTypes.MY_ACTION);

lastTime = new Date();

@Effect()
onMyActionWithAbort$ = this.onMyAction$
    .pipe(
        filter((data) => { 
          const result = new Date() - this.lastTime > 200; 
          this.lastTime = new Date(); 
          return result; 
        }),
        switchMap(this.DoTheJob.bind(this))
    );

@Effect()
onMyActionWithDebounce$ = this.onMyAction$
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        filter(this.preventDuplicateFilter.bind(this)),
        switchMap(this.DoTheJob.bind(this))
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution for Dart:

```
extension StreamExt<T> on Stream<T> {
  Stream<T> immediateDebounce(Duration duration) {
    var lastEmit = 0;
    return debounce((event) {
      if (_now - lastEmit < duration.inMilliseconds) {
        lastEmit = _now;
        return Stream.value(event).delay(duration);
      } else {
        lastEmit = _now;
        return Stream.value(event);
      }
    });
  }
}

int get _now =>  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/throttling-in-rxjava-2-d640ea5f7bf1) I ended up using the `throttleLatest` operator to get very similar behaviour to the immediate debounce I was looking for.

[image: throttleLatest marble diagram]

The following code will instantly emit the first item and then check for new items every 500ms. Only the latest event received within that 500ms window will be sent out.

```
observable.throttleLatest(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent making dual subscriptions
using this:

```
    const debouncedSkipFirstStream$ = stream$.pipe(
        map((it, index) => ({ it, index })),
        debounce(({ index }) => (
            index ? new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                : Rx.of(true))),
        map(({ it }) => it),
    );
```

if using split solution you will see 'run' print twice

```
x = rxjs.Observable.create(o=>{
    console.info('run');
    o.next(1);
    o.next(2);
});
a = x.pipe(rxjs.operators.take(1));
b = x.pipe(rxjs.operators.skip(1), rxjs.operators.debounceTime(60));
rxjs.concat(a, b).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with

```
Flowable.concat(

    flowable // emits immediately
        .take(1)
        .skipWhile { it.isEmpty() },

    flowable // same flowable, but emits with delay and debounce
        .debounce(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone looking for this in 2021:

```
@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
fun <T> Flow<T>.debounceImmediate(timeMillis: Long): Flow<T> =
    withIndex()
        .onEach { if (it.index != 0) delay(timeMillis) }
        .map { it.value }
```

Usage:

```
authRepository.login(loginDto)
                    .debounceImmediate(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   view.clicks()
            .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe {
                println("Clicked button")
            }
```

I found this the simplest way to do that. clicks() come from rx view binding. Add this dependency to get view observable

```
 implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding4:rxbinding:4.0.0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to solve the same problem using Kotlin Flow:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.throttleFirst(timeout: Duration): Flow<T> {
    var job = Job().apply { complete() }
    return onCompletion { job.cancel() }.run {
        flow {
            coroutineScope {
                collect { value ->
                    if (!job.isActive) {
                        emit(value)
                        job = launch { delay(timeout.inWholeMilliseconds) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```kotlin
flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(90)
    emit(2)
    delay(90)
    emit(3)
    delay(1010)
    emit(4)
    delay(1010)
    emit(5)
}.throttleFirst(1.seconds).collect { ... }
// 1, 4, 5
```

- [Ref](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1446#issuecomment-625244176)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const changes = this.form.valueChanges; // For example

const changesDebounced = changes.pipe(
    exhaustMap(change => merge(
        of(change),
        changes.pipe(startWith(change), debounceTime(500), take(1)),
    )),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
);
```

`changesDebounced` will emit immediately on changes. If subsequent changes occur, they are debounced (by 500ms). After no further values have been emitted for 500ms, `changesDebounced` will again emit immediately on the next change.

Using `exhaustMap` on the `changes` observable will ignore incoming changes while we execute the debounce logic.

Then we merge two observables: `of(change)` which will emit the change immediately, and also the debounced changes. Use `take(1)` so that we return control to the outer observable after the first debounced value is emitted. This lets us listen for changes again without debouncing.

Also notice that the debounced observable uses `startsWith(change)`. This is in case only one change is emitted within the debounce interval, meaning there are no other changes to debounce.

Lastly, we need `distinctUntilChanged()`. This is again in case only one change is emitted during the debounce interval. In that scenario, the debounced observable will emit the same value as the `of(change)` observable, so we can ignore the redundant emitted value.