# RxJava: Only emit if the first item for a given period

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I want to transform my source Flowable in such a way that events only go though if they are the first item within a specified period.

That is, I want the first item to go through and then drop all subsequent items until there was a period of, say, 10 seconds, in which no upstream event arrived.

Note that is this neither

- `debounce`: This would emit each item iff it was not followed by another one for 10 seconds - but this will force a 10 second delay on even the first item. I want to emit the first item right away.
- `throttleFirst`: This would emit the first item and then drop all subsequent items for 10 seconds after that first one. I want to have the blocking period reset after each upstream item.

I've now solved it like this:

```
source
  .flatMap { Flowable.just(1).concatWith(Flowable.just(-1).delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) }
  .scan(0, { x, y -> x + y })
  .map { it > 0 }
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter { it }
```

NOTE: I don't care about the actual items in `source`, only that they occur - but, of course, I could just wrap the items in a `Pair` along with `1` or `-1`).

Is there a simpler way to use built-in RxJava(2) Operators to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Sounds like a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964731/immediate-debounce-in-rx There is an extension operator for that https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersdebouncefirst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using the fact that `switchMap` only subscribes to one `Flowable` at once and using a boolean to check if it has to emit:

```
class ReduceThrottle<T>(val period: Long, val unit: TimeUnit) : FlowableTransformer<T, T> {
    override fun apply(upstream: Flowable<T>): Publisher<T> {
        return Flowable.defer {
            val doEmit = AtomicBoolean(true)

            upstream.switchMap { item ->
                val ret = if (doEmit.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    // We haven't emitted in the last 10 seconds, do the emission
                    Flowable.just(item)
                } else {
                    Flowable.empty()
                }

                ret.concatWith(Completable.timer(period, unit).andThen(Completable.fromAction {
                    // Once the timer successfully expires, reset the state
                    doEmit.set(true)
                }).toFlowable())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it is simply a matter of applying the transformer: `source.compose(ReduceThrottle(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))`.

Answer (score -1):

This might do what you need

```
source.debounce(item -> Observable.timer(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```