# Debounce without initial delay

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Is there an operator in RxJS that debounces without delaying the "first event in a burst", but delaying (and always emitting) the "last event in a burst"?

Something like this:

`---a----b-c-d-----e-f---`

after `awesome-debounce(2 dashes)` becomes:

`---a----b------d--e----f`

while a normal debounce would be:

`-----a---------d-------f`

It's kind of a mix between throttle and debounce...

Comment: So you want it to emit the first and last event in a time window?

Comment: Yes, but the time window behaves like with debounce (it get's extended with each event inside the window).

Comment: This is the actual answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145789/684869

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmmm, this is the easiest solution I can think of. The interesting part for you is the `awesomeDebounce()` function that creates the sub-chain.

It basically just combines `throttle()` and `debounceTime()` operators:

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const chai = require('chai');

let scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  chai.assert.deepEqual(actual, expected);
  console.log(actual);
});

function awesomeDebounce(source, timeWindow = 1000, scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.async) {
  let shared = source.share();
  let notification = shared
      .switchMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(timeWindow, scheduler))
      .publish();

  notification.connect();

  return shared
    .throttle(() => notification)
    .merge(shared.debounceTime(timeWindow, scheduler))
    .distinctUntilChanged();
}

let sourceMarbles =   '---a----b-c-d-----e-f---';
let expectedMarbles = '---a----b------d--e----f';

// Create the test Observable
let observable = scheduler
  .createHotObservable(sourceMarbles)
  .let(source => awesomeDebounce(source, 30, scheduler));

scheduler.expectObservable(observable).toBe(expectedMarbles);
scheduler.flush();
```

The inner `notification` Observable is used only for the `throttle()` operator so I can reset its timer manually when I need. I also had to turn this Observable into *"hot"* to be independent on the internal subscriptions from `throttle()`.

Comment: I'm going to award this answer a bounty for the nice demonstration and inclusion of marble tests. Just pending the 24 hour wait

Answer (score -1):

That's indeed useful debounce type for many situations. Use `merge`, `throttleTime` and `debounceTime` in a next way:

```js
Rx.Observable.merge(source.throttleTime(1000), source.debounceTime(2000))
```

Full example is here http://jsbin.com/godocuqiwo/edit?js,console

Note: it will emit not only first and last value in debounce interval but also values produced by throttle (which is usually expected and needed, as for scroll debouncing for example).