# RxJS - debounce event after throttle?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I let a user scroll a page and in every scroll event - I'm checking if there's a new items in the viewport
( *if there are , I do some operation on those new items - irrelevant for now*).

So I have something like this :

```
 const observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll');

  const subscriber = observable.throttleTime(300 /* ms */).subscribe(
          (x) => {
            console.log('Next: event!');
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('Error: %s', err);
          },
          () => {
            console.log('Completed');
          });
```

This code is working as expected  and I do see a message after each 300 ms.

But there's a problem. A user might scroll while not completing the 300 ms ( *event won't be raised*) and a new item got visible while scrolling.

This is where I need the `debounce` method.  (*which means "after  X ms of last event time - raise an event"*)

Which is exactly what I need.

[I've tried this](https://plnkr.co/edit/KjNyXdVTL5IsEmMMm1lj?p=preview)  :

```
 const subscriber = observable.throttleTime(300 /* ms */).debounceTime(350)....
```

But I only see the debounced events.

**Question**

How can I use throttle and at the end of a throttle -  attach a debounce ?

Comment: I think the solution would be something very close to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43104131/6680611).

Comment: Check if merging two streams: throttled and debounced works for you https://plnkr.co/edit/lHYVxSSrYA05wBWVqnqr?p=preview

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Indeed. thank you. Please post it as as an answer ( if you want)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could merge two streams: throttled and debounced into one using `merge`. [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/lHYVxSSrYA05wBWVqnqr?p=preview).

```
  const observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll');

  const subscriber = observable
      .throttleTime(300 /* ms */)
      .map(() => 'throttle')
      .merge(observable
              .debounceTime(350)
              .map(() => 'debounce')
      )
      .subscribe(
          (x) => {
            console.log('Next: event!', x);
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('Error: %s', err);
          },
          () => {
            console.log('Completed');
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

here is updated solution due to rxjs changes

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

const observable = fromEvent(window, 'scroll');

const subscriber = observable
  .pipe(
    throttleTime(300 /* ms */),
    map((data) => {
      console.log('throttle');
      console.log(window.pageYOffset);
      return data;
    }),
    debounceTime(350)
  )
  .subscribe(
    (x) => {
      console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('Error: %s', err);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Completed');
    }
  );
```

Comment: Better to use tap (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) rather than map