# Differentiate initial call with next emits in flowable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am currently subscribed to a flowable method using RxJava2
Let's say that i have a method where i subscribe.

```
public Flowable<UploadStatus> getStatusChanges()
```

I will make the first call to load all of the items status from database, so basically will load all of the items on my recyclerview.
But once im subscribe i will keep getting events from that flowable. I will get individual changes from a determined item, for instance a determined item changed.

How can i differ individual changes from the initial load?

Comment: any reason you are not using [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) ?

Comment: DiffUtils it is for a different use case, for updating the recyclerview itself.
What i really want it to differentiate the initial load with the updates afterwards.
The idea it is to show a loading bar or something first time when i subscribe to the flowable, then i will update the items changed on the recyclerview, but i want to know when the flowable finished with the first complete load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wrap your result into a class like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    public boolean firstLoad;
    public UploadStatus uploadStatus;

    //constructor omitted for brevity 
}
```

you could do something like this:

```
getStatusChanges()
    .map(item -> Wrapper(false, item))
    .startWith(Wrapper(true, null)
    .subscribe(result -> {
        if(result.firstLoad) {
            //show spinner
        } else {
            //handle normaly
        }
    })
```

Another approach (adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145789/1011435)) is using publish.

```
getStatusChanges().publish(items -> items.first().map(item -> Wrapper(true, item)).concatWith(items.skip(1).map(item -> Wrapper(false, item))))
```

Comment: Second aproach it more likely what i will use, thanks