# RxSwift: Deliver the first item immediately, debounce following items

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a textfield to validate, I want to disable a button whenever user is typing. After user stops typing (debounce by 1 second), the validation is carried out and the button is conditionally enabled based on the result. Notice the corner case when user typed only one character, validation should still happen.

```
--"a"-"ab"-"abc"------------------"ab"--"a"------------------"ab"-----------------

--false---------validate("abc")---false----validate("a")-----false--validate("ab")
```

This SO ([Deliver the first item immediately, 'debounce' following items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140044/deliver-the-first-item-immediately-debounce-following-items)) proposes the following solution in RxJava. But it seems only returns the very first element, not when user starts typing again after debounce? Correct me if I am wrong

```
Observable.from(items).publish(publishedItems -> 
    publishedItems.limit(1).concatWith(
        publishedItems.skip(1).debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    )
)
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that you want the button to be disabled whenever the user is typing, and when they are complete, to match the result of the validation function?

Comment: Exactly, whether they have completed typing is determined by `debounce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking, I was able to fully solve it in the following way, everything works as I intended

```
    let input = textField.rx.text.distinctUntilChanged()
    let keystroke = input.map { _ in Observable.just(false) }
    let validate = input
        .flatMap { Observable.from(optional: $0) }  // 1  
        .filter { $0.count >= minimumTextLength }      
        .debounce(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map { self.networkManager.validate($0).asObservable() } // 2
    return Observable.merge(keystroke, validate).switchLatest().distinctUntilChanged() // 3
```

1. Safely unwrap optional strings
2. `validate` returns `Single<Bool>` in my case, so I turn it into `Observable`. Notice I intentionally used `map` not `flatMap` in order to use the functionality `switchLatest` provides in step 3
3. I merge a and b to create an `Observable<Observable<Bool>>`, `switchLatest` allows me to ignore the `validate` result if user starts typing again. `distinctUntilChanged` discards repeated `false`s

Answer (score 1):

One option is to separate the question "is the user typing" from "is the input valid."

One (somewhat clumsy) way of describing whether the user is typing or not:

```
let isTyping = PublishSubject<Bool>()

textField.rx.text
    .map { _ in true }
    .bind(to: isTyping)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

textField.rx.text
    .debounce(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { _ in false}
    .bind(to: isTyping)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Then, you could describe the button enabled state like so:

```
isTyping.withLatestFrom(isValid) { !$0 && $1 }
            .bind(to: button.rx.isEnabled)
```

Of course for this approach to have an effect as soon as the user starts typing, it would be best for `isValid` to begin with a value.

You could also simplify this in the following manner. If these values are only used locally, this may be fine.

```
textField.rx.text
    .map { _ in false }
    .bind(to: button.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

textField.rx.text
    .debounce(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .flatMap { [weak self] in self?.validate($0) }
    .bind(to: button.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Note that with this approach, asynchronous validation operations would need to be canceled when the user resumes typing.

Hopefully, someone can suggest a cleaner solution, but I think this is a decent place to start.

Comment: I actually thought about the second approach as well. Is there a reactive way to cancel the async operation or ignore its result once user is typing again?

Comment: It's hard for me to answer this without knowing more about your application's network layer. The "sledgehammer" option for restarting observation in general is to reallocate the associated dispose bag, but I don't think that's what you want here.

One other option is to check that the textField hasn't changed during the course of validation: