# Deliver the first item as soon as it comes, debounce the following items

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

This question is the same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140044/deliver-the-first-item-immediately-debounce-following-items) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344309/rxswift-deliver-the-first-item-immediately-debounce-following-items), but about Kotlin flow.

What needs to be achieved:

- Deliver the first item as soon as it comes
- Debounce all the following items the way debounce function works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is simple solution with dynamic debounce timeout:

```
var firstEmission = true
flow.debounce {
    if (firstEmission) {
        firstEmission = false
        0L
    } else DEBOUNCE_TIMEOUT
}
```

Also possible to do this way:

```
merge(
    flow.take(1),
    flow.drop(1).debounce(DEBOUNCE_TIMEOUT)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
flow.withIndex().debounce {
    if(it.index == 0) {
        0L
    } else {
        1000L // your custom delay
    }
}.map {
    it.value
}
```